# Possible to get user profile information after login using hwioauthbundle in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, hwioauthbundle

I'm using `HWIOauthBundle` and `FOSUserBundle` on a Symfony2 application.

I have a situation where a user can opt to create a profile object at a step unrelated to logging in, and I would like to grab the data from their social profile at this step.

Is it possible to use HWIOauthBundle to get profile information from a service after the user has already logged in? I can create fields on the user object and store them there until they create the profile if necessary, but would prefer to skip this step if possible.

Answer (score 0):

follow the doc from the hwioauthbundle, you will create the FOSUBUserProvider.php.

check the function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse() in the file, dump the $response, you will see the user's profile info

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my case, i'm looking to do this after the user is already authenticated. They have the option to go to another page, and on that new page I would be looking to get additional data from the service. At the moment I'm storing all of the user data to their object when they log in, but this would still be useful if I could figure it out.